# Dynamic Objects

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Just curious as to how to modify a dynamic variable after creation.

I figure, I could just store them into some sort of list.

But I do assign them a name and event and wanted to know when the event is triggered would it be possible to modify the item with its name ?(object sender)

Edit Clarification:

On run time create new items and associate them with events.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.name = "Image" + someIntValue;
img.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(selectedImageClick);
someGrid.Children.add(img);
void selectedImageClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   //Modify that image e.g: border      
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question with perhaps a code sample?

Comment: @Tejs, hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to modify the sender, you'll have to cast it.  Your event handler would then look something like this:

```
void selectedImageClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    if (img != null)  // In case someone calls this event handler with something other than an Image
    {
        //Modify that image e.g: border
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much, anyway for the object to be multiple types ?

Comment: Well, you could do some run-time reflection to get the type of the object and check to see if it implements the method/property you are trying to affect.  Alternatively, you could use a nest of if/else's.
Third, and this is probably what you really want, is that you can test for a base type.  You may actually want to affect properties that are implemented by the Control class.  I would caution sending more than one or two types to a single Event Handler as it can start to become a twisted mess of conditional statements, making it harder to debug in the future.